# Why does bringing in a sibling module change the dependency rules/order of that module in gradle 5?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I have two modules:

- base-lib
- service

The `base-lib` has some Spring Boot/Security dependencies as well as some Azure ones. The Azure one needs a specific version of nimbusds so I have that dependency set to a specific version (5.64.4). When I build that first module by itself, gradle only downloads 5.64.4. But when I include it as a project dependency of the other module (which has *no* other dependencies), then it downloads **two** versions: 5.64.4 and 6.0. Why would this be different?

*base-lib: build.gradle*

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

group "${group}"
version "${version}"

sourceCompatibility = 11.0

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {

    api( [ "com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:5.64.4" ] )

    /* These are what pulls in 6.0 */
    api( [ "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}" ] )
    api( [ "org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:${springBootVersion}" ] )
    api( [ "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:${springOAuthClientVersion}" ] )

    //Microsoft Azure AD
    api( [ "com.microsoft.azure:adal4j:${adal4jVersion}" ] )

    /* elided, lot's of other dependencies here */
}
```

*service build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":base-lib")
}
```

If I delete the second module (`service`) and build the first, then it only downloads 5.64.4. But the moment I have both and build them, it pulls down 6.0 too.

This fixes it, but why is this needed *when pulling in as a project dependenency* and not normally? Why are the dependency rules different?

```
api( [ "com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:5.64.4" ] ) {
    force = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to trouble shoot such an issue is to use [the `dependencyInsight` task](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#sec:identifying_reason_dependency_selection) on the problematic dependency.

In your case, the most likely explanation is that your project `base-lib` makes use of the Spring boot and Spring dependency management plugins. These plugins will force a number of versions according to the Spring boot BOM but also have a [feature](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#dependency-management-configuration-bom-import-override-dependency-management) that makes any dependency declared with a version override what's coming from the BOM. And since you specify the version of `oauth2-oidc-sdk` it indeed gets that version.

Now when you pull transitively all these dependencies in `service`, the dependency management plugin is not applied. And thus default Gradle resolution rules apply, which means that between the `5.64.4` and `6.0` versions, Gradle will pick the highest.

Fixing can be done by forcing the version as you experimented or by applying the same plugins and declaring it again.